# JS animation performance with 'will-change' vs 'transformZ(0)'

Tags: javascript, animation, gsap, will-change

I've been trying out javascript animations and noticed performance differences when I was using `will-change` property and `transform3D()` to separate animated element to a new layer for gpu rendering.
It happens when I'm trying to animate `scaling` of the element, which also has a `border-radius` css property.
[Codepen here](https://codepen.io/DNFcode/pen/YeeVvN)

Without `will-change` property browser will perform additional **Rasterize Paint** (in rasterizer thread1 on a
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYJVo.png))

With `will-change` there is no **Rasterize Paint** action ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58y74.png)).

And it gets much worse when I'm trying to animate multiple elements at once in real-life project (especially it hurts on mobile). ([with will-change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkK2z.png), [without will-change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHWZA.png))

So the question is: how `will-change` manages to provide that kind of optimization even though it's supposed to do basically the same thing as `transformZ(0)` (creating new layer for gpu-rendering). And is there any way to optimize this animation without using `will-change`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`will-change` basically *does* the same thing (as of today) as the `translateZ(0)` hack: it pulls the element out onto a new rendering layer. The difference is that `will-change` is telling the browser your *intent*, namely, that you will be changing this property; whereas with `translateZ(0)` that is merely a coincidental side effect.

So `will-change` is just a more modern way of accomplishing the same thing, and as such, it's also [less widely supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=will-change) [than 3D transforms](https://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d).

It's conceivable that `will-change` will get more powerful over time. I can imagine it being used for colour changes (using a GPU shader), particular positioning changes (e.g. position of an absolutely positioned element), and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Thomas! I forgot I had this question :)
You're correct but I would like to add one more thing. Additionally to what `translateZ(0)` does, `will-change` has an ability to rasterize the layer. And thanks to that sometimes it can help to improve performance. The effect of rasterization could be easily seen during scaling up.
Here is a codepen to demonstrate [link](https://codepen.io/DNFcode/pen/YMaNZE)

Comment: Very interesting! Note that the `transform: translateZ(0);` in your codepen does nothing, because it's immediately overridden by an inline style applied by `TweenMax`. But that style uses `translate3d` so I suppose it has the same effect (and indeed I see both elements being created on separate layers).